# Order by numbers followed by alphabet and then null values

Tags: mysql, php

I have below column in my database:

```
abc
1
2
null
100
6
```

I want to sort and show these values as per below sequence:

```
1
2
6
100
abc
null
```

Anyone please help me to solve it.
Consider below query:

```
select * from test_table where status=1 order by test_column DESC
```

OR

```
 select * from test_table where status=1 order by if((test_column = '' OR test_column IS NULL),'999999',test_column) DESC
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your column? Please give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G`.

Comment: Column datatype is MEDIUMTEXT

Comment: And `SHOW CREATE TABLE\G`?

Comment: select * from table_Name order by Ename; Ename:-what you want arrange alphabetical order provide that specific column name.

Answer (score 5):

```
select
*
from
t
order by
case 
when col regexp '^[0-9]' then 1
when col regexp '^[a-zA-Z]' then 2
when col = '' or col is null then 3
end
, col * 1 /*this converts to number, so that 100 is not sorted before 2*/
, col /*finally sort strings correctly*/
```

Comment: String values can contain digits or another non-letter symbols ('1a', 'b2', 'a b', '1+2', etc.). I think move `then 2` to `else` part is more safe. And regexp for numbers is to be `regexp '^[0-9]+$'` to avoid '123abc' consider as number.

Answer (score 1):

With schema and data like this:

```
create table t1( data text);

insert into t1 (data) values ('100');
insert into t1 (data) values ('6');
insert into t1 (data) values ('1');
insert into t1 (data) values ('2');
insert into t1 (data) values ('abc');
insert into t1 (data) values (null);
```

you can run this query:

```
select data, 
case when length(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(data,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')) = 0 then 0 else case when data is null then 99 else 50 end end sort_,
case when length(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(data,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')) = 0 then CAST(data AS SIGNED) else 0 end int_
from t1 order by 2 asc, 3 asc;
```

with result:

```
+------+-------+------+
| data | sort_ | int_ |
+------+-------+------+
| 1    |     0 |    1 |
| 2    |     0 |    2 |
| 6    |     0 |    6 |
| 100  |     0 |  100 |
| abc  |    50 |    0 |
| NULL |    99 |    0 |
+------+-------+------+
```

Comment: And to avoid displaying `sort_` and `int_`, you can `SELECT data FROM (bigfoot's query) ORDER BY sort_, int_;`- see fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVVcn7jmHu9cz28xK7BXkb/1). I'm giving a +1 to this answer!

Comment: This answer is way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution as below :
Datatype of column is MEDIUMTEXT so i have converted string to numbers and used below solution :

```
Order by (test_column+0 != 'zzzzzz' IS NOT TRUE) ,test_column+0 ASC
```

OR

```
Order by (test_column+0 != 'zzzzzz' IS NOT TRUE) ,cast(test_column as unsigned) ASC
```

Comment: Please accept my deepest condolences.  How did you end up with such a mess?

Comment: What mess you find with it?

Comment: MySQL is a relational database.  It is unusual to put numbers in a mediumtext column.

Comment: Yes agree but it is already designed by someone else so I am working with it this way.Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: 1) `NULL` - before `'abc'`; 2) `'0'` value (if added) - the last. MySQL 5.7.19-log.

Comment: "designed" is also a very unusual choice of words, in this case.  You will learn a great deal from this colleague.  Things you should avoid in a next career, I mean.

Comment: What is this `(test_column+0 != 'zzzzzz' IS NOT TRUE)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.19-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table test (txt varchar(8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('abc'),(1),(2),(null),(100),(6),(0),('def'),('cde'),(0.4),(0.6);
Query OK, 11 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 11  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test order by cast(concat('0', txt)+0 as char)=txt DESC, 0+txt, txt;
+------+
| txt  |
+------+
| 0    |
| 0.4  |
| 0.6  |
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 6    |
| 100  |
| abc  |
| cde  |
| def  |
| NULL |
+------+
11 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Fails on negative numbers.